# Display some characters in a new file

Tags: c, structure

I want to read 'c' and "Hello world!!" but i see just the hexadecimal part.

Here the structure :

```
typedef struct step
{  

int n;

 char l;

 char c[25];                                                      

 } toto;




    int fd = open("one-structure.yolo", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 777);
    toto some;

    some.n = 212347;
    some.l = 'c';
    some.c[25]  = "Hello world!!";
    write(fd, &some.n, sizeof(int));
    write(fd, some.l, sizeof(char));
    write(fd, some.c, 13);

    close(fd);
```

the result : {=U@�f

Comment: You better use formatted read and write functions.

Comment: This should not have compiled on a conforming implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the problem pointed by ***Sourav Ghosh***.

You cannot assign string to array using assignment operator.

```
some.c[25]  = "Hello world!!";
```

You need to use `strcpy`.

```
   strcpy(some.c, "Hello world!!");
```

or

make `some.c` as pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kiran answer, you need to change `write(fd, some.l, sizeof(char));` to `write(fd, &some.l, sizeof(char));` as `write` needs a pointer.